# Reflecting canvas element to remote canvas element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, paint

I am developing an app in which two users A and B will be connected , both can see canvas element(programmed as paint console) on their screen and when any of user draws something on it, the other canvas reflects the same output as others.In short both can see same data on two different canvas element.
Well I don't want technical specifications but i like to know from where to begin what else i need to make it simplest other that Javascript/Jquery!
It will be very helpful if anyone could explain the whole process in brief as i am newbie in web development.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a simple overview:

- Track the mouse and record the strokes that are being drawn as for example objects which you store in an array
- Encode the array as a JSON object which you send to the server using Web Sockets.
- Receiver at the other end parses the JSON string back to Array + objects and then redraws them.

As both A and B now has the same data the canvases will draw the same content when they are redrawn. Then you can use several techniques to send just the new data, such as time stamp for last transmission, or a flag per object and so forth.

Comment: +1 Good advice...And a tool like either Socket.IO or SignalR would help with communication of that JSON data between the 2 users.  SocketIO: http://socket.io/  SignalR: http://www.asp.net/signalr